# How to install Box2D-qml with mingw32

Tags: qt, qml, box2d

My environment:
Qt 5.3.1 + Mingw32
Windows 7

I tired these:

1. Extract `box2d-qml` in `C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\mingw482_32\imports` and rename it as `Box2D`
2. Open cmd and `cd` into `Box2D`'s directory .
3. Input `qmake` in cmd, no output
4. Input `mingw32-make`, no error output.
5. Input `mingw32-make install`, no error output. and `Box2D.2.0` was generated under `C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\mingw482_32\qml` directory.

Then i create empty quick project and add `import Box2D 2.0` into qml.
Moving the mouse cursor on `import Box2D 2.0`,QtCreator pop up a message:
[image]

But when i run it got error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:///main.qml:3 plugin cannot be loaded for module "Box2D": ?v???O?C?? 'C:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/mingw482_32/qml/Box2D.2.0/Box2D.dll' ????? Qt ?????????????C?u???????g?p?????????B (?f?o?b?N???????[?X?????C?u?????????g?p???邱??????????)
```

The main Cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Probably you've mixed Qt versions or Debug/Release profiles. See my answer below how to install/use the plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options to use the plugin:

1. Installing into $QTPATH/qml (or $QTPATH/imports) folder as system-wide QML plugin. In this case you just have to do next steps:

   - download the source from Github and open it with QtCreator (don't put it into system folder, put the source into some user folder)
   - Go to Projects tab / Run / Add deploy step
   - add `install` to `Make arguments`
   - go to Edit tab, right click on the project and select `Run qmake`
   - now build the project (don't forget to set Release profile)
   - right click on the project and select `Deploy`;
   - The plugin dll (include all you need, Box2D code etc) will be installed into qt folder.

.

2. Compiling the plugin as part of your project. In this case you just have to do next steps:

   - download the source from Github and put the plugin source folder into your project folder (myproject/qml-box2d/, for example)
   - add the line into your .pro file: `include(qml-box2d/box2d_lib.pri)`
   - add this code into your main.cpp file:

   ```
   #include <box2dplugin.h> // <-- this line
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   ...
   Box2DPlugin plugin;            // and these
   plugin.registerTypes("Box2D"); // 2 lines
   ...
   }
   ```

   - Rerun qmake and recomplile the project. Now you can use `Box2D` items in your QML files.

Comment: Thanks, i missed add the last two lines in cpp code.